# Custom ListViewItem control shows class name where as regular ListView control shows actual data

Tags: c#, wpf

The following is the code snippet of WPF application where I am using ListView control and my custom ListView control but in the UI the custom ListView control shows the class name where as List View control shows the actual data [i.e. Text1 property value of Class1]. I know by overriding ToString() of Class1 my custom ListView shows actual data, but I do not want to override the ToString(). So is there a way to change the template of my custom ListView to work similar to how ListView control works ?

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window
                x:Class="Swip.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Custom.Controls;assembly=Custom.Controls"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Swip"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                Title="MainWindow"
                Width="525"
                Height="350"
                mc:Ignorable="d">

                <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance d:Type=local:MainWindowModel}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <controls:SwipableListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <controls:SwipableListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridView.Columns>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text1}" Header="11" />
                                </GridView.Columns>
                            </GridView>
                        </controls:SwipableListView.View>
                    </controls:SwipableListView>

                    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridView.Columns>
                                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Text1}" Header="11" />
                                </GridView.Columns>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>             
                </Grid>             
            </Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext=new MainWindowModel();
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class MainWindowModel
                {
                    public MainWindowModel()
                    {
                        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Class1>
                        {
                            new Class1(1),
                            new Class1(2),
                            new Class1(3),
                        };

                        this.DeleteCommand = new RoutedCommand("Delete", typeof(MainWindowModel));
                    }

                    public ObservableCollection<Class1> Items { get; private set; }

                    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
                }
```

**Custom control template**

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Custom_Control:SwipableListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="IsDeletePossible" Value="{Binding IsDeletePossible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Custom_Control:SwipableListView}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Brush_ContainerFill}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="48"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Brush_ContainerBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush_FontReadonly}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Custom_Control:SwipableListViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Button Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,5" x:Name="PART_DeleteButton" Content="{TemplateBinding ButtonText}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Brush_ActionBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Brush_ActionBackground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelectedForDelete" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_DeleteButton" Value="Visible"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Brush_FontReadonly}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: See [ListView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates). There is a `GridViewRowPresenter` instead of a `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: Yes that fixed the issue. I had tried it previously it didn't seem to work because there are multiple style themes in my solution and i was changing at the wrong place. Anyways thank you Clemens !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Clemens - By changing ContentPresenter to GridViewRowPresenter solved the issue.
Refer : [ListView Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates/)

Answer (score 0):

In my .net MAUI app on iOS, I solved this issue by wrapping everything inside of `DataTemplate` inside of a `ViewCell`. My `ListView` looks like this:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="SearchListView" SeparatorColor="Black" RowHeight="100"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewSearchResult, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="75,*,120" Padding="3" Margin="10">
                    <Border
                        WidthRequest="40"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20 20"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        StrokeThickness="0.1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ProfilePic}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                    </Border>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" TextColor="Black"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Button BackgroundColor="CornflowerBlue" Text="Add Friend" Grid.Column="2"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="35"
                        Clicked="AddFriendButton_Clicked" WidthRequest="105" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```